# Sed. How change line next to specific pattern

Tags: bash, sed

My file is:

```
DIVIDER  
Sometext_string

many  
lines  
of random  
text  
DIVIDER  
Another_Sometext_string  
many  
many  
lines  
DIVIDER  
Third_sometext_string  
....
```

How change lines following DIVIDER pattern

Result must be:

```
DIVIDER  
[begin]Sometext_string[end]

many 
lines  
of random  
text  
DIVIDER  
[begin]Another_Sometext_string[end]

many  
many  
lines  
DIVIDER  
[begin]Third_sometext_string[end]

....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be this would help -

```
sed '/DIVIDER/{n;s/.*/[begin]&[end]\n/;}' file1
```

**Execution:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file1
DIVIDER
Sometext_string

many
lines
of random
text
DIVIDER
Another_Sometext_string
many
many
lines
DIVIDER
Third_sometext_string

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed '/DIVIDER/{n;s/.*/[begin]&[end]\n/;}' file1
DIVIDER
[begin]Sometext_string[end]


many
lines
of random
text
DIVIDER
[begin]Another_Sometext_string[end]

many
many
lines
DIVIDER
[begin]Third_sometext_string[end]
```

**UPDATE:**

This version will handle one blank line after the first DIVIDER.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -e '0,/DIVIDER/{n;s/.*/[begin]&[end]/;}' -e '/DIVIDER/{n;s/.*/[begin]&[end]\n/;}' file1
DIVIDER
[begin]Sometext_string[end]

many
lines
of random
text
DIVIDER
[begin]Another_Sometext_string[end]

many
many
lines
DIVIDER
[begin]Third_sometext_string[end]

[jaypal:~/Temp]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

There are no other questions right now so that I thought I'd offer an alternate `awk` solution if you'd like? :)

```
awk '/DIVIDER/{print;getline;sub(/.*/,"[begin]&[end]");print;next}1' file1

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/DIVIDER/{print;getline;sub(/.*/,"[begin]&[end]\n");print;next}1' file1
DIVIDER
[begin]Sometext_string[end]


many
lines
of random
text
DIVIDER
[begin]Another_Sometext_string[end]

many
many
lines
DIVIDER
[begin]Third_sometext_string[end]

[jaypal:~/Temp]
```

This to handle first blank line after DIVIDER -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/DIVIDER/{count++;print;getline;if(count==1) sub(/.*/,"[begin]&[end]");else sub(/.*/,"[begin]&[end]\n");print;next}1' file1
DIVIDER
[begin]Sometext_string[end]

many
lines
of random
text
DIVIDER
[begin]Another_Sometext_string[end]

many
many
lines
DIVIDER
[begin]Third_sometext_string[end]

[jaypal:~/Temp]
```

Comment: I don't know if it's just my version of sed, but I had to use a semi-colon after the replacement line so it didn't think the closing bracket was a flag: `sed '/DIVIDER/{n;s/.*/[begin]&[end]\n/;}' file1`

Comment: Well I am not too sure, but having it won't hurt. I added another solution. I noticed there is one blank line after the first DIVIDER. If that is the case the sed would make it two blank lines after your first DIVIDER.

Comment: Nice solution. To emiliorate the deletion of the first blank line after the delimiter to cater for all such cases try this: `....;n:a;/^$/!b;N;s/\n//;ta}`