# changing next line after pattern with awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with thousands of lines whose contents are similar to this:

```
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
currentJob=job details ghi
queuedJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno
```

I want to change it to this:

```
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
completedJob=job details ghi
currentJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno
```

In other works, change `currentJob` to `completedJob` change next `queuedJob` to `currentJob`.

I have seen an answer to a similar problem that gives a `sed` and an `awk` solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336918/257233) but I couldn't work out how the ampersand is working as the second line in that answer, and how I could modify just part of the second line.

Comment: `&` gets all the matched chars in the replacement part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this,

```
$ cat test
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
currentJob=job details ghi
queuedJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno

$ sed '/^currentJob/{s/^currentJob/completedJob/;n;s/^queuedJob/currentJob/}' test
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
completedJob=job details ghi
currentJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^currentJob/` matches the line which startswith `currentJob`
- `s/^currentJob/completedJob/;` on that same line, replace `currentJob` with `completedJob`.
- `n;` Go to the next line.
- `s/^queuedJob/currentJob/` On the next line, replace starting `queuedJob` with `currentJob`

Comment: The explanation is really appreciated @Avinash - thank you for helping me learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F= 'f==1{$1="currentJob"; f=2} f==0 && /currentJob=/{$1="completedJob"; f=1} 1' OFS== test
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
completedJob=job details ghi
currentJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno
```

#### How it works

Awk implicitly reads through a file line by line.  Each line is divided into field.  This code uses one variable `f` which keeps track of where we are in the file relative to the `currentJob`.

- `-F=`

  This tells awk to treat `=` as the input field separator
- `f==1{$1="currentJob"; f=2}`

  Whenever the flag `f` is `1`, set the first field to `currentJob` and update `f` to `2`.
- `f==0 && /currentJob=/{$1="completedJob"; f=1}`

  If `f` is zero (or not yet set) and the first field is `currentJob`, update the first field to `completedJob`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-whole-line
- `OFS==`

  This tells awk to use `=` as the field separator on output.

Comment: oh wow, another sweet answer right as I marked the first one. Thanks @John1024, wish I could mark two answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
$1=="currentJob" { c=1 }
c==2 { $1="currentJob"; c=0 }
c==1 { $1="completedJob"; c++ }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
completedJob=job details ghi
currentJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the regex at the  end of line for our job.

```
awk '/ghi/{sub(/current/,"completed")}/jkl/{sub(/queued/,"current")}1' file
completedJob=job details abc
completedJob=job details def
completedJob=job details ghi
currentJob=job details jkl
queuedJob=job details mno
```